# Is there a way to change effective process name in Python?

Tags: python, process, arguments, hide, ps

Can I change effective process name of a Python script? I want to show a different name instead of the real name of the process when I get the system process list. In C I can set

```
strcpy(argv[0],"othername");
```

But in Python

```
argv[0] = "othername"
```

doesn't seem to work. When i get process list (with `ps ax` in my linux box) the real name doesn't change. I prefer a portable solution (or else one solution for posix and another for windows environments), if it exists.

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/427642/is-it-possible-to-set-the-process-name-with-pythonw, where http://bugs.python.org/issue5672 is mentionned

Comment: Is there a solution nowadays for Windows? (maybe with Python 3.x?) More precisely: The "Windows Task Manager" (CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE), tab "Processes", should display a custom string in the first column "Image Name" rather than just python.exe or pythonw.exe.  NB: another solution than duplicating python.exe to mycustomstring.exe ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put, there's no portable way.  You'll have to test for the system and use the preferred method for that system.

Further, I'm confused about what you mean by process names on Windows.

Do you mean a service name?  I presume so, because nothing else really makes any sense (at least to my non-Windows using brain).

If so, you need to use [Tim Golden's WMI interface](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi) and call the .Change method on the service... at least according to his [tutorial](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html).

For Linux none of the methods I found worked except for [this poorly packaged module](http://code.google.com/p/procname/) that sets argv[0] for you.

I don't even know if this will work on BSD variants (which does have a setproctitle system call).  I'm pretty sure argv[0] won't work on Solaris.

Comment: I know it's late, but for new readers, consider also @MattWritesCode [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13267122/248390), quick and simple for CPython on Linux.

Answer (score 99):

I've recently written a Python module to change the process title in a portable way: check https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle

It is a wrapper around the code used by PostgreSQL to perform the title change. It is currently tested against Linux and Mac OS X: Windows (with limited functionality) and BSD portings are on the way.

**Edit:** as of July 2010, the module works with BSD and with limited functionality on Windows, and has been ported to Python 3.x.

Comment: Can't install on windows.

Comment: @user never mind: it isn't very helpful on Windows but there's not much to do about it.

Comment: Is there a way to change the arguments displayed by ps -f? I don't really care about the program name (always python), but I want to change the displayed arguments.

Comment: @KillianDS: do you mean you want the output of "ps -f" different from the one of "ps"? You can't have it afaik.

Comment: That is not a Python module. It is a C module.

Comment: On Mac OSX this works for ps but not for top or the Activity Monitor.

Comment: This does not appear to change the equivalent of ``psutil.Process.name`` on MacOS 10.14, but works on RHEL 7.

Answer (score 59):

actually you need 2 things on linux: modify `argv[0]` from `C` (for `ps auxf` and friends) and call `prctl` with `PR_SET_NAME` flag.

There is absolutely no way to do first piece from python itself. Although, you can just change process name by calling prctl.

```
def set_proc_name(newname):
    from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    buff = create_string_buffer(len(newname)+1)
    buff.value = newname
    libc.prctl(15, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)

def get_proc_name():
    from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    buff = create_string_buffer(128)
    # 16 == PR_GET_NAME from <linux/prctl.h>
    libc.prctl(16, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)
    return buff.value

import sys
# sys.argv[0] == 'python'

# outputs 'python'
get_proc_name()

set_proc_name('testing yeah')

# outputs 'testing yeah'
get_proc_name()
```

`ps auxf` will show just 'python' after that :(. But `top` and `ps -A` will show new 'testing yeah' process name :). Also `killall` and `pkill` will work with new name.

btw, procname from googlecode also changes `argv[0]`, thus, even, changes `ps auxf` output.

**UPDATE**: The solution posted in this answer does not play nice sometimes on FreeBSD. I'm now using [py-setproctitle](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/) stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python/1866700#1866700) for a year or so on various linux and freebsd boxes. No fails so far! Everybody should too! :). It uses almost the same code as [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) [uses](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/misc/ps_status.c;hb=HEAD) in its main database and child processes.

Comment: procname doesn't work on PyPy (only on CPython) have to use setproctitle.

Comment: An equivalent and simpler implementation of your functions is to just write/read `/proc/self/comm`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68508813/427158

Answer (score 21):

Have a look on [setproctitle](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/) package

This is quite a portable version and works on many platforms.

```
pip install setproctitle
```

```
import setproctitle

setproctitle.setproctitle('new proc title as seen in top')
```

Comment: Beautiful simple solution here.

Comment: Works on Linux perfectly. Does not really work on Windows, and acknowledged as such by the doc of `setproctitle`. A true Windows solution is most likely difficult.

Answer (score 7):

My answer to similar question marked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255444/changing-the-process-name-of-a-python-script/25338292#25338292):

There is simplier (you don't need import any libs) but maybe not so elegant way. You have to do not use "env" inside the shebang line.

In other words, this will be named as "python" in process list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But this will be named with your scriptname:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

So you'll be able to find it with something like `pidof -x scriptname` or `ps -C scriptname`

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm not sure that simply settings `argv[0]` in a C program portably changes the name shown in `ps`.  Maybe it does in some unixen, but my understanding is that it's not expected to.

Second, since Windows is specifically non-POSIX compliant, only a few things are "portable" between POSIX and non-POSIX.  Since you specifically say 'ps', I'll assume that POSIX is your priority and Windows may not work.

More importantly, my understanding of changing `argv[0]` is that it requires a call to `exec` to make these changes.  Specifically, the `exec` call has both a path to an executable and a separate `argv` list.  Making your own call allows you to break the shell convention of putting the executable name in `argv[0]`.

You have [OS library process management](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management) which gives you direct access to the OS library for doing this.  You should consider breaking your script into two parts -- a starter and the "real work".  The starter establishes the run-time environment and exec's the real work with the desired parameters.

In C, you're replacing your own process with another.  In Python, you're replacing the old Python interpreter with a new one that has a different argv[0].  Hopefully, it won't balk at this.  Some programs check argv[0] to decide what they're doing.

You also have [subprocess.popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that you can use to set your desired args and executable.   In this case, however, the parent process should lingers around to collect the child when the child finishes.  The parent may not be doing anything more than a `Popen.wait`

Comment: No, changing argv in Linux (and likely other Unixes, but not all) does immediately change the visible process name, which is used by many widely-used programs to give descriptive names for their processes: both ssh and postgres do this, and some actively change their name on the fly to indicate their current status.  A Python module could be written to do this, using the Py_GetArgcArgv API call.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [python-prctl](http://packages.python.org/python-prctl/) to work very well under Linux. You will have to find something else for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support Linux and you just need to change the process name then you can simply write it to `/proc/self/comm`.

Example:

```
import os
import subprocess

print(subprocess.run(['pidof', 'foo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True))
print(subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'p', str(os.getpid()), '-o', 'pid,comm,cmd'],
        universal_newlines=True))

with open(f'/proc/self/comm', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foo')

print(subprocess.check_output(['pidof', 'foo'], universal_newlines=True))
print(subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'p', str(os.getpid()), '-o', 'pid,comm,cmd'],
    universal_newlines=True))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py argone argtwo
CompletedProcess(args=['pidof', 'foo'], returncode=1, stdout='')
    PID COMMAND         CMD
2881003 python3 test.py python3 test.py argone argtwo

2881003

    PID COMMAND         CMD
2881003 foo             python3 test.py argone argtwo
```

---

NB: On Linux, in a C program, writing to `argv[0]` just changes the argument in `/proc/self/cmdline` and **not** in `/proc/self/comm`. Thus, it doesn't affect `pidof`, the `top` COMMAND column, the `ps` COMMAND column, plain `pgrep` etc.

---

The [setproctitle](https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/) package supports multiple platforms and - on Linux - changes both the command and the argument vector. However, it's a C extension.

Answer (score -1):

One super hack on windows is to copy python.exe, rename it to process_name.exe, call your script using the renamed python.

Its a super hacky, but since there is not easy solution on windows and if one just needs to get it done quickly for that one single script to be able to monitor it, its a fair option.

In theory it could even be scripted... super duper hack!?

Answer (score -22):

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print sys.argv[0]
C:\Python25\scripts\ipython.py

In [3]: sys.argv[0] = 'foo'

In [4]: print sys.argv[0]
foo
```

Note the single '=' sign

Comment: But if i run ps (process list in linux boxes) the process name remain exactly the same. Try

Comment: This does not change the process name at all. It only changes Python's copy of argv. I would recommend deleting this obviously wrong answer.