# changing the process name of a python script

Tags: python, linux

Is there a way to change the name of a process running a python script on Linux?

When I do a `ps`, all I get are "python" process names.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/procname/

Sample usage:

```
# Lets rename:    
>>> procname.setprocname('My super name')    

# Lets check. Press Ctrl+Z       
user@comp:~/procname$ ps

    PID TTY TIME CMD 

13016 pts/2 00:00:00 bash

13128 pts/2 00:00:00 My super name <-- it's here
```

It will only work on systems where `prctl` system call is present and supports `PR_SET_NAME` command.

Comment: Neat!  Is there a way to perform the same operation **without** incurring the additional complexity of a `C` extension?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue5672 makes me think that, no, there isn't :-(

Comment: in that ticket, they also mention another process name-changing tool (also in C):  http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/source/browse/tools/

Comment: It looks like this package is no longer supported. I get an import error `undefined symbol: Py_InitModule3`

Comment: Thanks for that comment, David

Answer (score 23):

There is simplier (you don't need import any libs) but maybe not so elegant way. You have to do not use "env" inside the shebang line.

In other words, this will be named as "python" in process list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But this will be named with your scriptname:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

So you'll be able to find it with something like `pidof -x scriptname` or `ps -C scriptname`

Comment: Effective when we are working with bash files. Thank you.

Comment: Although that does defeat the purpose of using env.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber The "purpose" of env is [debatable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my/29620#29620) and generally not well understood by most people using it, anyway. The way I see it, this is just one more reason to _avoid_ prefixing with env.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work on centos 7, any idea why? I can still see python scriptname, even when I run from shell just use ./scriptname.py

Comment: @tesla1060, it works for me on centos 7. It should not depend on how you're launching script; please show your shebang line.

Comment: @SashaRu my shebang line:#!/usr/bin/env python, when running, it shows as python ./test.py in htop, the script is named test.py

Comment: @tesla1060 that is expected with using env. Try to change shebang to #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: @SashaRu still not right, i am getting /usr/bin/python ./test.py on my htop

Comment: @tesla1060, this question is about process cmd name in linux (man ps). Your question is about htop.

Answer (score 9):

the procname library didn't work for me on ubuntu. I went with setproctitle instead (`pip install setproctitle`). This is what gunicorn uses and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

There is the option of doing the following, though it only works on linux (with the [prctl(2)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/prctl.2.html) call)

```
if sys.platform == 'linux2':
    import ctypes
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    libc.prctl(15, 'My Simple App', 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Doesn't work Debian 6, x86_64.

Comment: neither works on ubuntu :(

Comment: Try replacing 16 with PR_SET_NAME

Comment: Successfully tested with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 / Linux 3.1.10 x86_64.
**Note:** it *does* change the name as seen in `ps` but not the cmdline as returned by `ps w`.

Comment: Python 3 (semicolons to denote lines because no multi-line on SO)
```
libc.prctl(15, b"New Name", None, None, None);
# And to retrieve: (I don't know if you have to initialize c_char_p with more than a single byte, but it seems more correct to allocate the correct amount of memory first);
proc_name = ctypes.c_char_p(b"\0" * 16);
libc.prctl(16, proc_name, None, None, None);
print(proc_name.value);
```