# How do I change the process name of an Erlang VM?

Tags: erlang

How do I change the process name of an Erlang VM?

It isn't very convenient to have `beam` listed when I do `ps -A`...

Somewhat related to: [changing the process name of a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255444/changing-the-process-name-of-a-python-script)

Comment: wouldn't give you "ps -elf" a detailed description of the command? would this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to overwrite the content of argv[0] in C in Linux. Now how to do that from erlang ... Well you might need to start the erlang process from within a C wrapper .. Just my 2 cent

Comment: here is more details: http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/10/linux-change-process-name.html