# How is a process named?

Tags: process, executable, tmux

I have a program called `xatelite`, that is literally a script in `/usr/local/bin/xatelite` that has the following content.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from xatelite import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

When I run this within a tmux instance, the pane takes the name `python3.6*`, because that is the process that is running. How do I make sure that the process is named `xatelite`. I want this to also be the case in `htop` and other programs that inspect processes.

Comment: The process is probably named `python3.6 xatelite` and `tmux` is only displaying the first word. Can you check in `ps aux | grep '[x]atelite'`?

Comment: You are correct, the process is named `/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/xatelite`. Is that because the shebang causes it to be executed it like that?

Comment: I think so, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255444/changing-the-process-name-of-a-python-script for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new session with

```
tmux new -n windowname program
```

Within the tmux session you can change the name of the window with `PREFIX + ,`