# How to set the process name of a shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, process

Is there any way to set the process name of a shell script? This is needed for killing this script with the `killall` command.

Comment: It's easy to do in `zsh`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170322/15513

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, it is a hack/workaround but it works pretty good. Feel free to tweak it to your needs, it certainly needs some checks on the symbolic link creation or using a tmp folder to avoid possible race conditions (if they are problematic in your case).

### Demonstration

***wrapper***

```
#!/bin/bash
script="./dummy"
newname="./killme"

rm -iv "$newname"

ln -s "$script" "$newname"

exec "$newname" "$@"
```

***dummy***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am $0"
echo "my params: $@"

ps aux | grep bash

echo "sleeping 10s... Kill me!"
sleep 10
```

Test it using:

```
chmod +x dummy wrapper
./wrapper some params
```

In another terminal, kill it using:

```
killall killme
```

---

### Notes

Make sure you can write in your current folder (current working directory).

If your current command is:

```
/path/to/file -q --params somefile1 somefile2
```

Set the ***script*** variable in ***wrapper*** to */path/to/file* (instead of *./dummy*) and call ***wrapper*** like this:

```
./wrapper -q --params somefile1 somefile2
```

Comment: This does not appear to change the actual process name as reflected by `/proc/$PID/comm` but rather changes the command as displayed in `ps` and `top`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this reliably and portably, as far as I know. On some flavors of Unix, changing what's in argv[0] will do the job. I don't believe there's a way to do that in most shells, though.

Here are some references on the topic.

- [Howto change a UNIX process and child process name by modifying argv0](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/processname.html)
- [Is there a way to change the effective process name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the kill command on a PID so what you can do is run something in the background, get its ID and kill it

PID of last job run in background can be obtained using `$!`.

`echo test & echo $!`

Comment: `kill %1` sends a signal to the 1st last job.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extremely old post.  Pretty sure the original poster got his/her answer long ago.  But for newcomers, thought I'd explain my own experience (after playing with bash for a half hour).  If you start a script by script name w/ something like:

`./script.sh`

the process name listed by ps will be "bash" (on my system).  However if you start a script by calling bash directly:

`/bin/bash script.sh`
`/bin/sh script.sh`
`bash script.sh`

you will end up with a process name that contains the name of the script.  e.g.:

`/bin/bash script.sh`

results in a process name of the same name.  This can be used to mark pids with a specific script name.  And, this can be useful to (for example) use the kill command to stop all processes (by pid) that have a process name containing said script name.

Answer (score 3):

You can all use the -f flag to pgrep/pkill which will search the entire command line rather than just the process name. E.g.

```
./script &
pkill -f script
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking to rename what shows in the `CMD` column of `ps -u username` just so I can kill the appropriate process easier. But searching and killing via `pkill -f myscript.py` is much more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

`exec` option `-a <name>` causes *the shell pass  as the zeroth argument to the executed command*, which allows for killing by name with `pkill`.

Not sure why earlier posters suggesting this option couldn't make use of it and withdrew their answers.

Demo:

```
~$ name=abc; ( echo "pid $BASHPID, name $name"; exec -a $name sleep 1m )&
[1] 580793
pid 580793, name abc

~$ pgrep -f -l abc
580793 sleep

~$ ps -fHww
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
max       180889   18726  0 Dec01 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash --noediting -i
max       580793  180889  0 03:42 pts/2    00:00:00   abc 1m
max       580799  180889  0 03:42 pts/2    00:00:00   ps -fHww

~$ pkill -f abc
[1]+  Terminated              ( echo "pid $BASHPID, name $name"; exec -a $name sleep 1m )
```

Note that it changes only the arguments array of the process, its executable name cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Include
`#![path to shell]`

Examples for `[path to shell]`:

1. `/usr/bin/bash`
2. `/bin/bash`
3. `/bin/sh`

Full example

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses a trivial python script, and the setproctitle package. For what it's worth:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import argv
from setproctitle import setproctitle
from subprocess import run
setproctitle(argv[1])
run(argv[2:])
```

Call it e.g. `run-with-title` and stick it in your path somewhere. Then use via

```
run-with-title <desired-title> <script-name> [<arg>...]
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux at least, `killall dvb` works even though `dvb` is a shell script labelled with `#!`.  The only trick is to make the script executable and invoke it by name, e.g.,

```
dvb watch abc write game7 from 9pm for 3:30
```

Running `ps` shows a process named

```
/usr/bin/lua5.1 dvb watch ...
```

but `killall dvb` takes it down.

Answer (score 0):

%1, %2... also do an adequate job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -ex

sleep 101 &
FIRSTPID=$!
sleep 102 &
SECONDPID=$!

echo $(ps ax|grep "^\(${FIRSTPID}\|${SECONDPID}\) ")
kill %2
echo $(ps ax|grep "^\(${FIRSTPID}\|${SECONDPID}\) ")
sleep 1
kill %1
echo $(ps ax|grep "^\(${FIRSTPID}\|${SECONDPID}\) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I put these two lines at the start of my scripts so I do not have to retype the script name each time I revise  the script.  It won't take $0 of you put it after the first shebang.   Maybe someone who actually knows can correct me but I believe this is because the script hasn't started until the second line so $0 doesn't exist until then:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#!/bin/bash ./$0
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bash` script with explicit call to `bash` (not just like `./test.sh`). Process name will contain script in this case and can be found by script name. Or by explicit call to `bash` with full path as
suggested in [display_name_11011's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476937/1455694):

```
bash test.sh                           # explicit bash mentioning
/bin/bash test.sh                      # or with full path to bash
ps aux | grep test.sh | grep -v grep   # searching PID by script name
```

If the first line in script (test.sh) explicitly specifies interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test script'
```

then it can be called without explicit `bash` mentioning to create process with name '/bin/bash test.sh':

```
./test.sh
ps aux | grep test.sh | grep -v grep
```

Also as dirty workaround it is possible to copy and use bash with custom name:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash_with_other_name
/usr/bin/bash_with_other_name test.sh
ps aux | grep bash_with_other_name | grep -v grep
```

Answer (score -1):

Erm... unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the name of a shell script is whatever you've named the file. If your script is named `foo` then `killall foo` will kill it.

Comment: Not true. Try it. Create a file called "tst.sh", make it executable, have it do something like a "sleep 30", and fire it up. You'll note that the process name associated with it is "/bin/sh" or "/bin/bash" or whatever you put in the shebang line.

Answer (score -2):

We won't be able to find `pid` of the shell script using "`ps -ef | grep {scriptName}`" unless the name of script is overridden using shebang. Although all the running shell scripts come in response of `"ps -ef | grep bash"`. But this will become trickier to identify the running process as there will be multiple bash processing running simultaneously.

So a better approach is to give an appropriate name to the shell script.

Edit the shell script file and use shebang (the very first line) to name the process e.g. `#!/bin/bash /scriptName.sh`

In this way we would be able to grep the process id of scriptName using

```
"ps -ef | grep {scriptName}"
```