# How to exit from bash script if it started with timeout?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, timeout, kill

I run my scripts with timeout function

```
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
```

How can I terminate script before timeout counted down?
Ctr+C does not work in this case
Closing terminal still leaves process on background

This is my full script:

```
python3 startmeVtest.py 5 2 10
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 10 4 20
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 20 4 40
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 30 8 50
timeout 86400 ./start.sh
sleep 4
python3 startmeVtest.py 50 9 70
./start.sh
exit 0
```

I would like to exit from my bash script before it finish without using ps -A all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the process name of a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075682/how-to-set-the-process-name-of-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

find a list of processes by name using grep

```
pgrep timeout
```

kill all processes by name

```
pkill timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will kill your start.sh script directly

```
pkill -f "start.sh"
```

Comment: This has the extra educational benefit of killing all scripts on the system named `start.sh` which will teach others not to use generic names.

Comment: That's true! :)