# How to set a child process name in subprocess?

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I want to set a name to the child process spawned by subprocess module.

`subprocess.Popen(["ls"])` spawns child process named `ls`, but I want to set a custom name of the process. For example, if I open `top` instead of process showed by name `ls`, it will be showed by custom name e.g. `list-all-files` set by me. How can I do that by using subprocess module or any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python

Comment: @gnr: that's about changing the process name *from within the process*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good pt

Answer (score 0):

How about using a link and aliasing?

```
user@localhost: ln -s /bin/ls list-all-files
user@localhost: alias ls list-all-files
```

When you now run `subprocess.Popen(['ls'])` you'll only see a process `list-all-files` running in a ps/top.

Otherwise a bash wrapper might be a good way to go.