# Easy way to tell apart python multiprocessing's OS processes

Tags: python, linux, python-multiprocessing

**Summary**

I'd like to use the Python multiprocessing module to run multiple jobs in parallel on a Linux server. Further, I'd like to be able to look at the running processes with `top` or `ps` and `kill` one of them but let the others run.

However, what I'm seeing is that every process launched from the Python multiprocessing module looks identical to the `ps -f` command.

All I'm seeing is this:

```
fermion:workspace ross$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 32257 32256   0  8:52PM ttys000    0:00.04 -bash
  501 32333 32257   0  9:05PM ttys000    0:00.04 python ./parallel_jobs.py
  501 32334 32333   0  9:05PM ttys000    0:00.00 python ./parallel_jobs.py
  501 32335 32333   0  9:05PM ttys000    0:00.00 python ./parallel_jobs.py
  501 32336 32333   0  9:05PM ttys000    0:00.00 python ./parallel_jobs.py
  501 32272 32271   0  8:53PM ttys001    0:00.05 -bash
```

**Is there any way to get something more descriptive in the CMD column? Do I need to just keep track of PIDs in log files? Or is there another option?**

**Background**

I am doing some batch processing where some jobs can run for hours. I need to be able to run some of those jobs in parallel to save time. And all those parallel jobs need to complete successfully before I can run another job that depends on them all. However, if one job is misbehaving I want to be able to kill it while letting the others complete... and this goes one where I have one job, then parallel jobs, then a few more jobs in sequence, then some more parallel jobs...

**Example code**

This is some dummy code that outlines the concept of what I'm trying to do.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import multiprocessing

def open_zoo_cages():
    print('Opening zoo cages...')

def crossing_road(animal, sleep_time):
    print('An ' + animal + ' is crossing the road')
    for i in range(5):
        print("It's a wide road for " + animal + " to cross...")
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

    print('The ' + animal + ' is across.')

def aardvark():
    crossing_road('aardvark', 2)

def badger():
    crossing_road('badger', 4)

def cougar():
    crossing_road('cougar', 3)

def clean_the_road():
    print('Cleaning off the road of animal droppings...')

def print_exit_code(process):
    print(process.name + " exit code: " + str(process.exitcode))

def main():
    # Run a single job that must finish before running some jobs in parallel
    open_zoo_cages()

    # Run some jobs in parallel
    amos = multiprocessing.Process(name='aardvark Amos', target=aardvark)
    betty = multiprocessing.Process(name='badger Betty', target=badger)
    carl = multiprocessing.Process(name='cougar Carl', target=cougar)

    amos.start()
    betty.start()
    carl.start()

    amos.join()
    betty.join()
    carl.join()

    print_exit_code(amos)
    print_exit_code(betty)
    print_exit_code(carl)

    # Run another job (clean_the_road) if all the parallel jobs finished in 
    # success. Otherwise end in error.
    if amos.exitcode == 0 and betty.exitcode == 0 and carl.exitcode == 0:
        clean_the_road()
    else:
        sys.exit('Not all animals finished crossing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, I noted that putting one of the functions in another Python module doesn't change what goes in the `ps` command column for the associated process.

**Output**

```
fermion:workspace ross$ ./parallel_jobs.py 
Opening zoo cages...
An aardvark is crossing the road
It's a wide road for aardvark to cross...
An badger is crossing the road
It's a wide road for badger to cross...
An cougar is crossing the road
It's a wide road for cougar to cross...
It's a wide road for aardvark to cross...
It's a wide road for cougar to cross...
It's a wide road for aardvark to cross...
It's a wide road for badger to cross...
It's a wide road for cougar to cross...
It's a wide road for aardvark to cross...
It's a wide road for badger to cross...
It's a wide road for aardvark to cross...
It's a wide road for cougar to cross...
The aardvark is across.
It's a wide road for badger to cross...
It's a wide road for cougar to cross...
The cougar is across.
It's a wide road for badger to cross...
The badger is across.
aardvark Amos exit code: 0
badger Betty exit code: 0
cougar Carl exit code: 0
Cleaning off the road of animal droppings...
```

Comment: checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python..  one of the answers mentions https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle which may work for you. It doesn't look like there is a way to do this in vanilla python.

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. I think I'd have to use multiprocessing.current_process().pid and then use that python library (written in C, it seems) to change the process name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice easy answer, have each process open a descriptive file handle, and then use lsof.

```
f = open('/tmp/hippo.txt','w')
```

this will give you the pid for your process

```
lsof | grep "hippo"
```

it's not the most pythonic answer, but so what : )

My initial answer was the easy way, here is an incomplete tiny example of larger concept, adding signal handler to the class being called as a subprocess, allows you to issue something like a kill -6 ... to dump out info .... you can even use it to on demand dump out progress of how much is left to process in a given subprocess,

```
import signal

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.myname = name
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.my_callback)
        self.myqueue = Queue.Queue()

    def my_callback(self):
        logging.error("%s %s %s", self.myname, psutil.blah_getmypid(), len(self.myqueue))
```

Or you can do this, which i think may be what you really want:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def foo():
    time.sleep(60)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = [
        multiprocessing.Process(name="a",target=foo),
        multiprocessing.Process(name="b",target=foo),
        multiprocessing.Process(name="c",target=foo),
    ]
    for p in process:
        p.start()
    for p in process:
        print(p.name, p.pid)
    for p in process:
        p.join()
```

Comment: This worked worked really well on my Mac laptop. I will try on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

Psutil library can do what you are looking for and is widely used. You can learn how the psutil programmer do it or use the library yourself in your project.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Comment: This library looks really neat. However, I'm not sure what would distinguish between the processes. I looked at name(), exe(), and cmdline() methods of the Process class and they give the same thing for each of my multiprocessing processes. (At least on my Mac laptop... will try again on Linux.) Is there something else I should try?

Comment: I think you need to look for children() and parent(). The jobs you start in parallel should be children of the parent script that starts them.

Comment: What I want is to be able to distinguish between the children of the parent process. Which one is which? I can tell the parent/child relationship just using `ps`.

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is a parent process parent() is None.

Comment: While psutil looks very cool, I'm thinking it doesn't do what I need. The main script creates N child processes... let's say 4 child processes. Those 4 sibling processes are *not* dividing up a large amount of work into 4 pieces. Instead they are doing 4 *different* things. I decide I need to kill one of those 4 sibling processes. I do not want to kill any of the other 3 sibling processes. How can I tell which of those 4 sibling processes is the one I want to kill? They all have the same parent.

Comment: If you are launching processes with specific functionality why don't you store your self process pid? Like `this_process_does_this.pid` and `that_process_does_that.pid` I have seen some linux daemons working like that with files stored at /var/run (or temp, check your platform) I quick read or cat to pid file will give you pid and then you can do whatever you need with that process.