# custom linux daemon won't stop using "service stop"

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, start-stop-daemon, pyinotify

I've written a custom python daemon that runs as a service via an init.d script on ubuntu 14.04. Starting the service works fine, but when I try to do "service monitor stop", the daemon is not terminated. I'm using pyinotify to daemonize a file watcher for changes.

Within the init.d script:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Monitor files"
NAME=monitor
DAEMON=/usr/bin/python
DAEMON_ARGS="/home/user/python/monitor.py"
PIDFILE=/home/user/logs/monitor.pid
LOGFILE=/home/user/logs/monitor.log
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
```

...

```
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
    echo "done"
}
```

...

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
```

...

To ensure the daemon handles SIGERM properly, I can run it by hand:

```
bash$ /usr/bin/python /home/user/python/monitor.py
bash$ kill -Term PID
```

The daemon successfully handles the SIGTERM and exits properly.

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't handle it when I do "service monitor stop" though.

Comment: While it's running, does the `PIDFILE` contain the correct process ID? From your command-line example it looks like `monitor.py` turns itself into a background process, so `start-stop-daemon` might be recording the wrong PID

Comment: My previous comment assumes that `start-stop-daemon` has been told `--make-pidfile`, as otherwise it's up to `monitor.py` to write it out. (`do_start` isn't in the question)

Comment: Yes that's correct, the python program does turn itself into a background process, and the PID in the PIDFILE matches the PID of the process. And yes, it makes its own PIDFILE within the python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the process `$NAME` is correct, as delivered to the `start-stop-daemon --stop` command. I just encountered this issue because a process I was running ended up getting a different name whenever it forked its daemon. Try running this to see the process command name:

```
ps -o comm= $(cat /home/user/logs/monitor.pid)
```

I bet yours outputs this (instead of `monitor`):

```
python
```

Then change your stop command to look like this, where you substitute `python` in place of `$NAME`:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name python
```

Comment: Yep, you're 100% right. The process had been renamed to python. Your suggestion fixes it.

As a follow up, could adding "python" after --name conflict with some other system process? Is there a better practice to get my daemon properly named?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python). It might not be worth all that effort; if your `$PIDFILE` is properly secured (not writeable by untrusted users) then the risk should be pretty low that you'd end up killing the wrong Python-based process. As long as `$PIDFILE` lives in `/var/run` (which is usually tmpfs), it'll be zapped on a reboot, which would lessen the odds further.