# How to change the process name in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

When I want to run Python in terminal, I would like to type `ABC` instead of typing `python`.

How to change the process name in Ubuntu?

ex) python -> ABC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change effective process name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python)

Comment: I think you are looking for the `alias` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
alias 'ABC=python'
```

Then `ABC` will call python...

If you want to make it permanent, add this line to your [`.bash_profile`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29239/where-is-bash-profile)