# Python Tkinter window name on bottom bar always shows "Tk"

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I made a Tkinter program, and it's working fine except that the title on the bottom bar on Ubuntu (or whatever you call it) shows the window name as "Tk" whatever I do. I'm really bothered by this. Is there someone who knows a fix?

Comment: Did you try `root.title("...")`

Comment: Of course, that only changes the window title, but not the title on the bottom bar.

Comment: Could we see what it looks like?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006607/14094985) answer and the related post could help?

Comment: I presume this is a ubuntu specific problem because on wIndows it works just well.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it. Also, when running Windows programs using Wine, it says "Wine Windows Program Loader" on the bottom but the title on the window works fine.

Comment: AST's answer looks fine, but I am afraid that it will only work on Linux, as I am trying to make it portable.