# How to change streamlit process name in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, operating-system, streamlit

There are two streamlits apps are running in my server, when the apps are deployed in Ubuntu VM server, we execute the following command

```
$ nohup streamlit run dashboard1.py >data.out 2>&1 &
$ nohup streamlit run dashboard2.py >data.out 2>&1 &
```

it creates the processes like

```bash
adminr@micro:~/$ ps -e | grep streamlit
132803 pts/0 00:00:10 streamlit
156959 pts/0 00:00:02 streamlit
```

can we change the process name from streamlit to custom name like “dashboard_sale” and “dashboard_college”. This would be easy for manage and redeploy.

Please help

I tired alreay python setproctitle package but it is not working

```py
import streamlit as st
import setproctitle # installed pip install setproctitle

# Set the process title
setproctitle.setproctitle("dashboard_sale")

# Streamlit app content
def main():
    st.title("Streamlit App with Process Title")

    st.write("This is a simple Streamlit app that sets the process title.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Packages requiered for running this code

```
pip install streamlit setproctitle
```

Comment: I don't mean to rush you, but was my answer of any use?  I'm curious about the matter myself, so I'd like to know how you decided to proceed for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of [Is there a way to change effective process name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564695/is-there-a-way-to-change-effective-process-name-in-python/68508813#68508813).

Briefly: it seems simplest to write your desired command name to /proc/self/comm.

Note that this method changes the command *name*, not the command *line*.  Anything that reports the command line won't be affected, which is why eg. "ps a" and "ps x" will show the name of the executable rather than your custom name(s).

- The change will be visible for "ps -e", which you indicate is how you're checking process names.
- The change will also be visible for "pstree"
- The change will *not* be visible for "ps" if you use flags such as "a", "x", etc.

As I understand it, if you want the custom name(s) to be visible as part of the command line, you'll need to create executables named appropriately.

--klode